# Composable to bitmap without displaying it

Tags: android, bitmap, composable

When using classic `View`s it is easy to obtain a bitmap from a view without displaying it. I create the view class through a `LayoutInflater`, and then, since it hasn't been attached to a view, I measure it first.
I have the following extension function which measures it and draws the view on a bitmap:

```
fun View.toBitmap(width, height): Bitmap {
    this.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
    )
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.measuredWidth, this.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    this.layout(0, 0, this.measuredWidth, this.measuredHeight)
    this.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

When using `Composable`s I can't succeed in exporting a bitmap from a view.

I imagined something like this:

```
class MyComposableView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): AbstractComposeView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        MyComposable()
    }
}
```

What I did is instancing a `MyComposableView` with the application context, and then I tried to obtain a bitmap with the extension function `toBitmap`.
The result is the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate windowRecomposer; View io.myapp.MyComposableView{f66ecdd V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not attached to a window
```

What I can't understand is why the exception is thrown for the `AbstractComposeView` but is not thrown for the view obtained through the inflater.

---

EDIT:
on 09 Apr. 2022 it seems there's not a solution other than using a classic XML layout.

Comment: You can use my answer. It is possible without xml. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74814850/11819708

Answer (score 1):

There's a way for it to capture the composable content by rendering composable content into an Invisible window and capturing it secretly from there.

### Create a invisible composable

```
@Composable
fun InvisibleContent(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val windowManager = context.getSystemService<WindowManager>()!!

    DisposableEffect(key1 = content) {
        val composeView = ComposeView(context).apply {
            setParentCompositionContext(null)
            setContent {
                content()
            }
            setOwners(context.findActivity())
        }

        windowManager.addView(
            /* view = */ composeView,
            /* params = */ WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                /* w = */ WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                /* h = */ WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                /* _type = */ WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL,
                /* _flags = */ WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                /* _format = */ PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )
        )

        onDispose { windowManager.removeView(composeView) }
    }
}

private fun View.setOwners(fromActivity: ComponentActivity) {
    if (findViewTreeLifecycleOwner() == null) {
        setViewTreeLifecycleOwner(fromActivity)
    }
    if (findViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner() == null) {
        setViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner(fromActivity)
    }
    if (findViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner() == null) {
        setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(fromActivity)
    }
}

/**
 * Traverses through this [Context] and finds [Activity] wrapped inside it.
 */
private fun Context.findActivity(): ComponentActivity {
    var context = this
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is ComponentActivity) return context
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    throw IllegalStateException("Unable to retrieve Activity from the current context")
}
```

### Capture a composable from the above composable (Example)

In this example, using [Capturable](https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable) to capture the content because it uses the Compose canvas to draw picture.

```
@Composable
fun CaptureDemo() {
    val captureController = rememberCaptureController()
    val uiScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    InvisibleContent {
        ContentToCaptureComposable(modifier = Modifier.capturable(captureController))
    }
    
    Button(
        onClick = {
            uiScope.launch {
               contentBitmap = captureController.captureAsync().await()
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text("Capture content Image")
    }
}
```

Here, the content of the `ContentToCaptureComposable` composable won't be displayed on the UI and it won't take place in the UI in the same View along with relative composables. Instead, it'll secretly added on another window with no visibility.

I've tried this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

### You can do that without *xml layout* like this by flowing below steps and implement functions :

```kotlin
BitmapComposable(
    onBitmapped = { bitmap ->
        // Do your operation
    },
    intSize = IntSize(500, 700) // Pixel size for output bitmap
) {
    // Composable that you want to convert to a bitmap
    // This scope is @Composable
    YourComposable()
}
```

---

#### 1 - Copy this functions :

***Note that this composable will not display anything on screen !***

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BitmapComposable(
    onBitmapped: (bitmap: Bitmap) -> Unit = { _ -> },
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.Transparent,
    dpSize : DpSize,
    composable: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .size(0.dp, 0.dp)
        .verticalScroll(
            rememberScrollState(), enabled = false
        )
        .horizontalScroll(
            rememberScrollState(), enabled = false
        )) {

        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(dpSize)) {
            AndroidView(factory = {
                ComposeView(it).apply {
                    setContent {
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.background(backgroundColor).fillMaxSize()) {
                            composable()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), update = {
                it.run {
                    doOnLayout {
                        onBitmapped(drawToBitmap())
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun BitmapComposable(
    onBitmapped: (bitmap: Bitmap) -> Unit = { _ -> },
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.Transparent,
    intSize : IntSize, // Pixel size for output bitmap
    composable: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val renderComposableSize = LocalDensity.current.run { intSize.toSize().toDpSize() }
    BitmapComposable(onBitmapped,backgroundColor,renderComposableSize,composable)
}
```

#### 2 - And use like this :

```kotlin
BitmapComposable(
    onBitmapped = { bitmap ->
        // Do your operation
    },
    backgroundColor = Color.White,
    intSize = IntSize(500, 700) // Pixel size for output bitmap
) {
    // Composable that you want to convert to a bitmap
    // This scope is @Composable
    YourComposable()
}
```

Comment: Do you have source for the above answer?

Comment: No. Obtained by myself through trial and error and combining several methods.